# How to find representatives of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})/SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$

Tags: nt.number-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, na.numerical-analysis

While reading about the Teichmuller flow, I am reading about the space of lattices $SL(2,\mathbb{R})/SL(2, \mathbb{Z})$.

I could not a find a good way of computing the Teichmuller flow on this quotient space because I have no way of deciding that two elements are in nearby cosets.

$$ X = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right) \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{cc} e^t & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-t} \end{array}\right)X
= \left(\begin{array}{ll} a\, e^t & b \, e^t \\ c \, e^{-t} & d \, e^{-t}\end{array}\right)$$

From a numerical point of view, two coefficients are getting very exponentially large and the others are exponentially small and we need row reduction to keep them in a fundamental domain.

How do we keep track of the cosets?  Perhaps it is easier to just write the geodesic flow on the unit tangent bundle, but then I still have to keep reverting back to the fundamental domain.

---

I one had a copy of Arnoux's "[Le codage du flot géodésique sur la surface modulaire](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/view?pid=ensmat-001:1994:40::185)" but now I can't find it.  Many papers talk about some of the math details, but the coding is still rather messy.

In response to recent questions about the meaning of the word **compute** I have found an entry from the dictionary as well as [9,380](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=compute) instances of the word on MathOverflow and [38,883](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=compute) instances on Math.SE

[image]

Comment: I doubt there is a good way to compute this, because the geodesic flow you are looking at is strongly chaotic (ergodic, mixing, Anosov etc.).

Comment: @coudy: But it is not Anosov, is it? If you start with two $x$'s at distance $\epsilon$ apart, the $n$-th iterates are at distance at most $n\epsilon$ apart. Unlike in the case of the geodesic flow on $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})/\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ where the distance grows exponentially. At any rate, this is not my field of expertise, I just thought the OP observed something (namely unstability of the orbits) that has a theoretical basis.

Comment: @GHfromMO I am being contractictory.  Numerically, due to the chaotic nature of this map, this problem is intractible!  Unless I pick directions - no longer generic - where this map can be exactly computed.

Comment: @coudy, the Kronecker system (rotation) is an almost periodic map (or periodic in the rational case)!, certainly not mixing/expansive in any way. It's computation (or more specifically, cutting sequence and Poincare section) is related to the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{2}$. GH, the image of the iterates stay in the same distance throughout the orbit (hence also $0$ entropy).

Comment: @GH Translations of the circle are not mixing nor Anosov indeed, I was thinking of the map $x\mapsto 2x$ on the circle. Let me give an example of an Anosov mixing map for which the iterates can be computed: the cat map $x\mapsto  {\tiny \pmatrix{1&1\cr 0& 1\cr}}x$ on ${\bf R}^2/{\bf Z}^2$. The coefficients of its powers are given by the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks for the correction, I was typing too quickly.

Comment: @coudy: Thanks for this example. I am sure the geodesic flow is more complex in many ways, so perhaps my meta claims can still be justified, but I am not qualified to do so!

Comment: @coudy , the map you've written is not the cat map, the cat map is hyperbolic. The iterates can't be computed easily for that map, for the same reason (it is Bernoulli). The map you've defined is just a simple shearing.

Comment: @Asaf. Yes I am sorry. I wanted to write $x\mapsto {\tiny \pmatrix{1&1\cr 1&0\cr}}x$, which is the square root of the cat map and is Anosov, mixing, etc. Its iterates can be expressed in term of the Fibonacci numbers. The short window left for editing comments is annoying.

Comment: @Asaf The powers are explicitely given by ${\tiny \pmatrix{1 & 1 \cr 1 & 0 \cr}}^n = {\tiny \pmatrix{F_{n+1} & F_n \cr F_n & F_{n-1}\cr}}$ where $(F_n)$ is the Fibonacci sequence. I hope there is no typo this time.

Comment: @coudy, I've meant to compute explicitly the iterates of a certain point to arbitrary precision, because of Bernoullicity of the system (which is basically the problem with the geodesic flow as-well).

Comment: @Asaf The only time you can compute to arbitrary precision is when on points which are not generic (and not all generic points are trivial).  I start to wonder if these "generic"  points exist at all.

Comment: @johnmangual , I don't understand your terminology (what is "to compute" or what is "generic" in your terms). In Ergoidc Theory, generic points have a definite meaning and one can show that Lebesgue a.e. point is generic. About the non-generic points, in those cases, there are non-generic points (actually, the exceptional set is of full dimension) that can have rather strange behavior (their orbit can be  contained inside a fractal say, or have a dense orbit which is not equidistributed).

Comment: @Asaf Perhaps you can put an answer below explaining why my choice of words is ambiguous?

Comment: @GH. There is some confusion about what is an Anosov flow/diffeo. The geodesic flow is Anosov on the unit tangent bundle of a compact hyperbolic manifold. However, the distance between two orbits does NOT grow exponentially, by triangular inequality:  $d(g^t v, g^t w)\le 2t+d(v,w)$. The exponential growth/decay holds infinitesimally, for the differential.

Comment: @BarbaraSchapira: Thanks for your comment. I think the OP's question concerned the geodesic flow on the unit tangent bundle of the upper half-plane, and how it projects on the unit tangent bundle of the modular surface. Here, certain distances blow up exponentially, which explains the OP's numerical instability and difficulties. Or at least this is what I meant in my first comment (on May 13 at 17:33).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "computing" the Teichmuller flow, but the standard way to visualize the flow is through the Poincare upper-half plane model.

Recall that $PSL_2({\bf Z})$ acts through homographies on the Poincare half-plane ${\bf H}=\{z=x+iy \in {\bf C} \mid Im(z)>0\}$ and on its unit tangent bundle $T^1{\bf H}$. This bundle is identified to $PSL_2({\bf R})$ through the isomorphism 
 $$
\Psi\Bigl(
{\small \pmatrix{1 & x \cr 0 & 1 \cr}}
{\small \pmatrix{\sqrt{y} & 0 \cr 0 & 1/\sqrt{y} \cr}}
{\small \pmatrix{\cos({\theta\over 2}) 
        & \sin({\theta\over 2}) \cr -\sin({\theta\over 2}) 
        & \cos({\theta \over 2}) \cr}}\Bigr) = (x,y,\theta)
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between the vector and the vertical direction.

The quotient of $T^1{\bf H}$ by the action of $PSL_2({\bf Z})$ is isomorphic to $SL_2({\bf R})/SL_2({\bf Z})$. It is customary to represent the quotient space ${\bf H}/PSL_2({\bf Z})$ through the Dirichlet fundamental [domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group#Tessellation_of_the_hyperbolic_plane) of $2i$, which is given by 
$$
D = \{ z\in {\bf H} \mid |z| \geq 1, \ |Re(z)| \leq 1/2\}.
$$

[image]

Your Teichmuller flow is the geodesic flow associated to the -1 curvature metric on $\bf H$ and the projection of its trajectories on $D$ are circles orthogonal to the boundary of $\bf H$. So what happens when such circle crosses the boundary of $D$?
If it crosses one of the two vertical lines, then you translate it with $z\mapsto z \pm 1$ to bring it back in $D$. If it crosses the piece of unit circle, you apply $z\mapsto -1/z$ and then you translate it back to the central strip. Iterate until you reach $D$, don't forget to keep track of the angle. Translate it back to its matrix form and this gives you the representative you are looking for.

Geometrically, the trajectory of the flow is made of pieces of circles in $D$ that start to fill $D$ (or $T^1D$) densely for almost all initial starting vectors.

If you look at the action of $z\mapsto z+1$ and $z\mapsto -1/z$ on the end points of the circle that lie on the boundary of $\bf H$, you can see that this is just the standard algorithm that computes the continuous fraction decomposition of the (endpoints of the trajectory associated to the) initial vector. This is the standard coding of the geodesic flow on the modular surface, described in a famous paper of Caroline Series ("The modular surface and continued fractions", jlms, 1985).